# Graphical issues with tippy.js (popper.js) resulting from positioning with transform in Chrome

Tags: webkit, popper.js, tippyjs

Inside a `tippy-js v6.3.7` tooltip, I have a 1px height div with `background-color: #333`. The div is randomly appearing blurred on some tooltips and not others. Removing the `transform` property on data-tippy-root fixes it but positions the tooltip in the upper-left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem resulted from the `transform` property used to position the tooltip itself. Tippy v6 uses popper v2, which defaults to positioning this way. You can disable it via popper's `gpuAcceleration` setting.  Here's how I fixed it through Tippy.

```
opts = {
    ...opts,
    popperOptions: {
        modifiers: [{
            name: 'computeStyles',
            options: {
                gpuAcceleration: false, // true by default
            },
        }]
    }
}

tp = tippy(elem, opts);
```

Firefox did not have this rendering problem, and both Chrome 94 and 96 did.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer saved me a ton of time, thanks Vael Victus! One more thing: you are missing a pair of {}, it should be:

```
popperOptions={{ modifiers: [{ name: 'computeStyles', options: { gpuAcceleration: false } }] }}
```

Comment: Hmm, I double-checked and the code I'm using is working without them; it actually breaks with yours!